# Change Slack Bot Icon from Post PHP

Tags: php, slack, slack-api

We post a message to a slack channel every time a customer does a specific task. We want to change the bot Icon based on what is being posted in the channel.

Is this possible?

```
public static function send_to_slack($message,$title = null){

    $body = array();
    $body['text'] = '';
    $body['icon_url'] = '';
    if(!empty($title)) $body['text'] .= "*$title*\n";
    $body['text'] .= $message;

    $iconURL = "https://img.icons8.com/emoji/96/000000/penguin--v2.png";

    $body['icon_url'] .= $iconURL;

    $json = json_encode($body);
    
    //Test Slack Channel
    $slack = "SLACKURL"

    $response = wp_remote_post( $slack, array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'body' => $json,
        )
    );

    if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

From Slack:
You cannot override the default channel (chosen by the user who installed your app), username, or icon when you're using Incoming Webhooks to post messages. Instead, these values will always inherit from the associated Slack app configuration.

*** UPDATE
I just ran into this situation. My old app was using the old web hooks. I had to create a new integration and ran into this issue. The simple solution is to install the slack app called "Incoming Webhooks". It's made by slack. It will allow you to generate an older style webhook that will allow you to post to any channel.

Comment: Okay, can I use chat.postmessage instead to accomplish this?

Comment: I use https://packagist.org/packages/maknz/slack on an older project and it allows me to override the channel with no problems. I suspect that it may be because the webhook is several years old that it has some default permission that newly created ones do not. As the other poster mentioned, maybe try and update the auth scope.

Answer (score 0):

Found the correct way. Make sure you enable chat:write.customize in Slack oAuth Scope.

```
 public static function send_to_slack($message,$title = null){

    $ch = curl_init("https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage");
    $data = http_build_query([
        "token" => "BOT-TOKEN",
        "channel" => "CHANNELID", //"#mychannel",
        "text" => $message, //"Hello, Foo-Bar channel message.",
        "username" => "MySlackBot",
        "icon_url" => $iconURL
    ]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;

}
```